# How can revoke token in multi authenticate in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, revoke-token

I wrote a login method, and it worked. My auth config:

```
   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin-web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
```

The I wrote a logout method like:

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admin-web')->logout();
        $value = $request->bearerToken();
        $id = (new Parser())->parse($value)->getHeader('jti');
        $token = $request->user()->tokens->find($id);
    }
```

but it fails to find tokens in this column:

```
    $token = $request->user()->tokens->find($id);
```

and throws an error:

```
Trying to get property 'tokens' of non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call `Auth::guard('admin-web')->logout()` you will not be able to retrieve the user from the request.
You have to retrieve the token before logging out the user:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
      $value = $request->bearerToken();
      $id = (new Parser())->parse($value)->getHeader('jti');
      $token = $request->user('admin-web')->tokens->find($id);
      Auth::guard('admin-web')->logout();
}
```

Comment: Do you get the user when you add the guard to the `user()` method? I updated the answer.

Comment: i updated my answer, but it not true. i have same error. do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you get the user with `Auth::guard('admin-web')->user();`?

Comment: No,i have null answer.

Comment: Are you sure you signed the user in with the correct guard?

Comment: i think Auth::guard('admin-web')->user() is null. i lost my user

Answer (score 0):

Use as like below and check it back You have missed the $id parameter.

```
 public function logout(Request $request,$id)
  {
  $value = $request->bearerToken();
  $id = (new Parser())->parse($value)->getHeader('jti');
  $token = $request->user('admin-web')->tokens->find($id);
  \Auth::guard('admin-web')->logout();
  }
```

Comment: it not working. i don't  get the user with Auth::guard('admin-web')->user() in my controller. when i signed  i get user with Auth::guard('admin-web')->user() but in other functions does not exist

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Use like this (Request $request,$id)

Comment: i used POSTMAN. i don't need id.

Comment: in construct  method set a special data?